# What is best practice for creating Year on Year columns in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table with many columns containing various metrics by year & week:

```
 Year Week_Number Metric1 Metric2
 ---- ----------- ------- -------
 2020 1           11      21
 2019 1           10      20
```

I need to add columns calculating Year On Year growth for each of these metrics to use on a report; the data needs to look something like this:

```
 Year Week_Number Metric1 Metric2 Metric1_YOY Metric2_YOY
 ---- ----------- ------- ------- ----------- -----------
 2020 1           11      21      10%         5%
 2019 1           10      20      N/A         N/A
```

I can do this using DAX, but there are a lot of columns needed and it takes a lot of time to copy my formula, create a new column, paste the formula in, edit it, and repeat for each column.

Does anyone know of a quicker, more efficient way to create a lot of columns quickly please?

Comment: I would consider a matrix view based on a table with 3 columns Metric name, Date, Value. Maybe I am overlooking a dimension. We can help you further when you give more details on data, table structure and result what you need

Comment: @aldert: When you say a matrix, do you mean a matrix visual, or is this something that can be created in query editor?

Comment: I would suggest showing a example of the data, you maybe able to use tabular editor and calculation groups for year on year measures

Comment: Thanks; I've added some example data; hopefully this makes what I'm asking clearer!